# magento-shipworks: the remote server returned an error (405) method not allowed

Tags: magento

I am trying to connect Magento with Shipworks, for that i have downloaded shipworks3.php file which is required for the integration,

and i have put the file in the `c://wamp/www/magento/shipworks3.php`, that time Shipworks giving me message that it requires SSL required, to resolve that i made my apache SSL enable using IIS7, so it will use the https:// url ,

error resolved that time but got new error, about

```
the remote server returned an error (405) method not allowed
```

I have searched a lot but found nothing, can anyone sort it out,

Thanks in advance.